# Get property from helper return value

Tags: handlebars.js

So, i have a little handlebars helper, for example

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('getTest', () => { test: 'test' });
```

If i call this helper in template, can i use something like this

```
{{(getTest).test}}
```

Trying to use different brackets, like with arrays [ ], didn't helped.

I think, it can be done.

Thanks!

Comment: please provide a more detailed example of your problem

Answer (score 4):

In this case we should use `{{#with}}` helper. So, in my case, final code is

```
{{#with (getTest)}}
  {{test}}
{{/with}}
```

> You might find a helper like this useful if a section of your JSON object contains deeply nested properties, and you want to avoid repeating the parent name.

[block helpers docs](https://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html)

Answer (score -1):

As per the Handlebars syntax, you should call your helper as,

```
{{getTest test}}
```

Also, consider updating your helper function as below if you just require the helper to return the `test` value back to the template.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('getTest', (val) => {return val});
```

Tested using http://tryhandlebarsjs.com.

Hope this helps.

Comment: In template i have
`{{#if (lookup ../libraries name).js}} ...`
I can write special helpers, but it's a hard way, i think.

Comment: You need to elaborate on what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: I tried to avoid any specific parts of my code, 'cause it's actually a lot bigger. I wrote abstract code, that completely shows what i trying to achieve.

Comment: Its still unclear. You want to reduce the template code or helper code or both? The purpose of helpers is to get the data and context from the template level, do manipulations with it and return a desired result onto the template. Thus, in the template, we can't reduce the code as we are forced to follow the handlebars syntax there. If you could describe your use-cases and logic more, we could try to optimise your helper code and produce the same output.